# jquery find by index in a list

Tags: jquery, list, select

```
<ul>
  <li>No</li>
  <li>Yes</li>
  <li>No</li>
</ul>

//demostration purpose 
$('ul').get(2).text();


//output = Yes
```

What's the best way to access a specific item in a list? and use it as a selector?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to get the jQuery object in a list:

```
$('ul li').eq(1).text();
//or:
$('ul :eq(1)').text();
```

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BU6et/). When you get [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) you're getting a DOM element, which doesn't have any jQuery functions on it.  Remember that both of these are *0-based* so you'll need `1` to get the "Yes" in your example.

There are also other [basic filters you may be interested in](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-filter-selectors/), for example [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) (less-than-index), [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) (greater-than-index), [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) and several others.

Comment: @Andy - Was noticing in my example page, just woke up :)

Comment: `nth-child(n)` doesn't accept a zero-based number so I used to always confuse the two and have to double-check.  Really, it's the spec's fault for being inconsistent.  Anyway, I only edited it to justify my +1 :p

Comment: @Andy - Agreed, I consider `:nth-child()` a red-headed step-child at this point, I actually so rarely use the thing in practical everyday usage anyway.  Maybe once we drop support for IE7 *and* IE8 (already dropped 6, wooohoo!) I can start using it for something in CSS, but in jQuery I've found it not to be very useful at all.

Comment: Just thinking about the day people can drop support for IE8 brings a joyful tear to my eye ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) filter selector:

```
$('ul li:eq(0)').text(); // gets first li
$('ul li:eq(1)').text(); // gets second li
$('ul li:eq(2)').text(); // gets third li
// and so on
```